# how to change text size in tableView

Tags: ios, uitableview

Can anyone tell me how to change the text size in a tableView so that the text in the screenshot below fits within the width of the screen:

[image]

The current tableView code is:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath)
    cell.textLabel!.text = self.dataArray[indexPath.row]
    cell.imageView!.image = UIImage(named: "20x20_empty-round-radiobutton-choice-ui")
       return cell
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: go to textLabel properties in storyboard and change autoshrink to other option

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following code:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath)
    cell.textLabel!.text = self.dataArray[indexPath.row]
    cell.textLabel.font = UIFont(name: cell.textLabel.font.fontName, size:15) // Change the font size as per your requirement
    cell.imageView!.image = UIImage(named: "20x20_empty-round-radiobutton-choice-ui")
       return cell
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Set autoshrink minimum fontScale. If your text is long enough to exceed the actual Label Frame,then your font will be shrinked upto minimum font scale you provide in storyboard or xib.

[image: Auto Shrink minimum font scale 0.5]